# How to give new Heroku collaborators access?

Tags: heroku, collaboration

I have one personal Heroku app that I've added a collaborator to. He shows up in the Access tab with role "Collaborator" and no permission listed; however, he is able to deploy code and everything.

I want to add this same person to another app. When I do so, he shows up identically in the Access tab, but he can't see the app from his own dashboard. When I execute `heroku access -a <my-app>`, he is not listed. There don't seem to be any settings at all for this in the UI or in the CLI. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that this can only be done through the CLI. The UI on the website *looks* like it does it, but it doesn't. Here's the CLI command:

```
heroku access:add <email@address> --app <app-name> --permissions deploy,manage,operate
```